# CORS issue with Vue.js and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cors

I used vuejs with nodejs, with the vue client address `http://localhost:8000`, the nodejs server addresses `http://localhost:3000`.

When calling api, I get cors error `CORS preflight channel did not succeed request headers`

request

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Host:localhost: 3000 
Origin:http://localhost: 8000
```

response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT,PATH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
```

error in response is `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI`

Comment: Yes, you cannot make cross domain requests without configuring CORS. Using another port is also viewed as a cross-origin domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `expressjs` you can simply use [nodejs cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) lib to enable CORS in your node server.

I strongly advise you to activate it only for dev purposes :

```js
var cors = require('cors')

if (NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
   app.use(cors())
}
```

Comment: Why do you strongly advise to do so? Could you make examples, why CORS is dangerous with certain configurations (cross-origin requests from malicious servers if opened to anyone etc.).

Comment: If he doesn't know about CORS, I'm not sure he is ready for advanced configuration to keep CORS enabled in production. But you are right, you can always leave cors enabled with proper configuration.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 not sure if it's the point of the question to demonstrate why CORS headers are required, plus [the official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) provide security use cases

Comment: @Maelig if you will not activate it on prod then the issue will be same, allow cors manually or using cors NPM, you always can whitelist origins.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin

Comment: Thank you, my problem has been solved, but can you explain why my header config does not work. Specifically, when i call method post width parameter, it receives the above error

Comment: @HieuNguyen I guess your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` was missing some header definitions, just use `*` if you want to accept all headers

Comment: so what is the solution for vue js ? we need to use express ? no direct solution available?

Comment: vuejs is a client framework, if you need to enable cors you have to do it on server side