# CORS issue with Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I used vuejs, with address http://localhost:8000.

When calling api, I get CORS error. Sid not succeed request headers
request

> Domain from origin `http://localhost:8080` has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```js
let headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: How to [run Chrome without CORS](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS issue with Vue.js and Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127155/cors-issue-with-vue-js-and-nodejs) or [“Access-Control-Allow-Origin” CORS issue when using Vue.js for client side and Express for server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877747/access-control-allow-origin-cors-issue-when-using-vue-js-for-client-side-and-e)

Comment: @Phil the solution in that page is not working for me. I need a solution to allow cors from vue. I can not update site B (which I am getting to fetch)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a "vue.config.js" with proxy configuration.

Example :

```
 module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only work for OP's local dev server. It also means all the requests will need to be to relative `/api` URLs. `localhost:8080` is OP's client-side service, not the API

Comment: what does 'ws: true' stand for?

Answer (score -1):

Three Options

Option 1. Edit Vue.config.js

> ```
>  module.exports = {
>       devServer: {
>         proxy: {
>           '/api': {
>             target: 'http://localhost:8081',
>             ws: true,
>             changeOrigin: true
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

Option 2 (Temporary/Test use case)

1. Use Cors Plugin in chrome Eg- Moseif CORS
2. Degrade your chrome version less than 71
3. Use chromium or Canary Browser.

Option 3

1. Look into your server Cors allowed or not you can add plugin for python cors and annotation for java on server to allow this call.